# Add Image to MapViewAnnotation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I am trying to add an image to my MKAnnotation. I have the code below. How would I add @"map_icon.png" to this? Any help would be great. Thank you!

**mapView.m file:**

```
// retrieve latitude and longitude from the dictionary entry

location.latitude = [dictionary[@"placeLatitude"] doubleValue];
location.longitude = [dictionary[@"placeLongitude"] doubleValue];

// create the annotation

newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:dictionary[@"name"]
                                               andCoordinate:location];
```

**MapViewAnnotation.m file**

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d 
{
title = ttl;
coordinate = c2d;
return self;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do this by responding to `mapView:viewForAnnotation`, e.g.:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapViewAnnotation class]])
    {
        MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                        reuseIdentifier:@"MyCustomAnnotation"];
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_icon.png"];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

        // If you've added the QuartzCore.framework to your project, you can also add a shadows/borders/etc.
        // For example, this code adds a shadow
        //            
        // [annotationView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
        // [annotationView.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8f];
        // [annotationView.layer setShadowRadius:5.0f];
        // [annotationView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 0)];
        // [annotationView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        return annotationView;
    }

    // Note, if the annotation isn't your custom annotation (e.g. a `MKUserAnnotation`)
    // then return nil so default behavior will take place.

    return nil;
}
```

For more information, please see [Adding Annotations to a Map](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW33) section of the *Location Awareness Programming Guide.*

Comment: Hi Rob! I plopped that into my MapViewController.m file and I get an error on this line: - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(CompassDirectionAnnotation *)annotation - the error says "Expected a type"

Comment: @Brandon Sorry, that was my custom annotation type. I've replaced it with the generic reference (i.e., an object that conforms to `MKAnnotation` protocol). See above.

Comment: Dude.. You are so good.. THANK YOU - I am posting some related questions shortly... Quick SO question, am I able to allocate more points to someone?

Comment: That's kind of you, but please don't worry about it. Just pay it forward (i.e. help someone else out in the future).

Comment: Strange question. when I click the icon, the bubble no longer pops up.

Comment: @Brandon Set `canShowCallout` as appropriate, as in the revised answer.

Answer (score 2):

Implement the MKMapViewDelegate in your mapView Controller

```
myMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
myMapView.delegate = self;
```

Implement the method in your mapView Controller

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
```

If you want a custom image to replace the default pin

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapViewAnnotation class]])
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annotation"];
    [annotationView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_icon.png"]];
    return annotationView;
}
return nil;
}
```

If you want an image in the callout bubble

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapViewAnnotation class]])
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annotation"];
    UIImageView *pin = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5, -5, 10, 10)];
    [pin setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_icon.png"]];
    annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = pin;
    return annotationView;
}
return nil;
}
```

Comment: Hi Peter, I put the implementation of the KMMapViewDelegate in the viewDidLoad, then added the method below it. In the method, I am getting the warning "control reaches end of non-void function". Any ideas?

Comment: @Brandon I left out the rest of the implementation and kept in what was relevant, I edited to include the rest which is pretty much what Rob has ( you need the isKindOfClass check so that if it's the user location pin, it shows the default blue circle instead of your pin )